# SVG is rendered with a line through the middle in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, chromium, inkscape

I don't have any experience with SVG but I was hoping to use this one in a project I'm working on.

http://openclipart.org/people/aungkarns/sakura1.svg

The problem is that in Google Chrome and Chromium, a thin line is rendered from the top flower, right through the image to down near the stem. In other browsers, in the image viewer in Ubuntu and in Inkscape, this line isn't shown. I don't think it's supposed to be there, so is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is the path with id "path2164", (the first path node in Layer 1), if you view the source and remove this element, it will disappear. I don't really know why it doesn't render in other browsers, it may be malformed. At any rate, if you remove it, the image looks normal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. All the data in the SVG file was a little daunting but with your advice the problem was easily fixed.